# zend_validate_regex not happy with accented characters

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-validate, non-ascii-characters

so I'm using Zend_Framework and I  need to validate a text and accept not only digits and normal letters, but also some guys like 'ã', 'ç' and so on...

I was confident that a simple regex validation would do the job:

```
    public function SetTitle($title) 
    {
      $validator = new Zend_Validate_Regex('/^[0-9a-zA-ZÀ-ú]+[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ú\'\-\.:,; ]{1,50}$/');

      if ($validator->isValid($title)) {
        if ($this->title != $title) {
            $this->title = $title;
        }
      } else {
        throw new MyApp_Projects_ProjectException("This ($title) is not a valid title.");
      }

} //SetTitle
```

and it really worked when, after some thinking reported below, I test something like this:

```
public function testIfCanAttributeTitleToProject()
{            
    $someTitle = "some title with ç, á and ã";
    $this->project->SetTitle($someTitle);
    $this->assertEquals($this->project->getTitle(), $someTitle);
}
```

But, when I try to add a validator to check data at the form, like this:

```
    $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('title');
    $title->setLabel('Nome:')
        ->setOptions(array('size' => '50'))
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addValidator('Regex', false, array(
            'pattern' => "/^[0-9a-zA-ZÀ-ú]+[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ú\'\-\.,: ]{1,50}$/"
            ))
        ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim');
    // attach elements to form
    $this->addElement($title);
```

a error is raised when I try to test

```
public function testUserCanUseAccentedCharacters() {

   $form = new MyApp_Form_ProjectCreate();
   $formData = array(
       'title' => 'we scream to weird chars like ã é or ç',
       'submit' => true
       );
    $form->process($formData);
}
```

where process function is like:

```
public function process($data) 
{
    if ($this->isValid($data) !== true) {
        throw new MyApp_Form_ProjectCreateException('Invalid data!');
    } else {
        $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
        $projectMapper = new MyApp_Projects_ProjectMapper($db);        
        $project = new MyApp_Projects_Project();
        $project->SetTitle($this->title->GetValue());
        $projectMapper->insert($project);
    }
}
```

I have already checked and retested the regular expression in other contexts and it seems OK, but for some reason, even as Zend_Validate itself works with this expression, a validator inside a form element doesn't accept anything inside the À-ú range...

For sure I'm (still) losing something basic here... or banging my head against a wall when I have some better way around...

Do someone may help me, please?

TIA, again... :)

Comment: (1) When you say "the error is raised," do you mean that MyApp_Projects_ProjectException is thrown? (2) Are you sure that À-ú is the problem?  What happens when you remove just the À-ú from the regex?

Comment: (1) Yep, this is the exception being thrown. (2) I was using the expression without À-ú and it was fine (although I didn't tried some title with comma, for sure...), but then I realized that this characters were not being accepted and I need to use it. As I eexplained in the edited post above, now I can validate the text using this expression, but when I try to do it inside a form, using Zend_Form_Element_Text and add Validator, the same expression doesn't work. Txs again for your attention, David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'/^[0-9a-zA-ZÀ-ú]+[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ú\'\-\. ]{1,50}$/'
```

embeds a single quote.  Will this work for you?

```
"/^[0-9a-zA-ZÀ-ú]+[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ú\'\-\. ]{1,50}$/"
```

**Update**

Three more things to try.  I don't know the details of Zend's implementation of regular expressions, so I don't know whether the first two will work.

The Unicode Letter property:

```
"/^([0-9]\p{Letter})+([0-9\'\-\. ]\p{Letter}){1,50}$/"
```

The Posix character class:

```
"/^([0-9][[:alpha:]])+([0-9\'\-\. ][[:alpha:]]){1,50}$/"
```

Brute force enumeration of the letters you care about:

```
"/^[0-9a-zA-ZÀÁÂ ...et cetera... øùú]+[0-9A-Za-zÀÁÂ ...et cetera... øùú\'\-\. ]{1,50}$/"
```

Comment: Txs David for making me think a little more... There was nothing about the quote, but I have noticed that I was lacking to accept the comma... :-/

Comment: txs again, I tried the three things without success... Actually, only the last one didn't break other tests... 
But, I´ve found that my problem when processing the form is related with some filter instead of the validate itself. I will make some researches in this field, and bring results here...  Txs agai for your time!

Comment: well, in the end, after removing all flaws caused by the organic component between my chair and my keyboard, the problem was related to HtmlEntities filter. Don't really undesrstand why it was bothering with this chars, but I will avoid its use for now, and deal with this concern some other way.